Can't get schema names from Dynamics 365 into SQL Server
In simple terms, I am trying to export my Dynamics 365 Database into SQL Server after doing some transformations using Power Query through PowerBI Desktop. I have been successful using DAX Studio to export all the tables into SQL server, but it does not bring over the schema names, and it's really a problem for queries.
Steps I have done:

Connect PowerBI Desktop to Dataverse, bring in tables, and transform data. Save.
Open Dax Studio, connect to powerbi Data model.
In DAX studio, go to advanced tab, export data to SQL server.

All works except that it brings over stuff like Address 1 (main address) instead of Address_line_1.
I am open to getting the data from Dynamics to SQL Server a completely different way but a few considerations:

the total DB is over 10 GB and I only have SQL server express. I did the transformations so I could get it under the 10 GB limit.
I already have all the stuff figured out in power query (transformed data) so I would like to leverage that if possible.

Thanks in advance!
